# Create an async function that returns type according to a boolean param

Tags: typescript

I was trying to create an asynchronous function in TypeScript with proper types return. The function would have a boolean parameter that determines the return type of the function. I searched on the internet and it seems that using type conditional is the way to go.

I implemented the code more or less like in the following:

```ts
type Foo = {
    propA: string
    propB: string
}

type Bar = Omit<Foo, 'propB'> & {propC: string}

type ConditionalFooBar<T extends boolean> = T extends true? Foo:Bar

async function mainFunction<T extends boolean>(param:T) : Promise<ConditionalFooBar<T>>{
    // Some function awaits happened here
    if(param===true){
        return {
            propA: "a string",
            propB: "a string"
        }
    }
    return {
        propA: "a string",
        propC: "a string"
    }
}
```

With this code, the TypeScript compiler complained the following at the first return statement:

```
Type '{ propA: string; propB: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ConditionalFooBar<T>'.ts(2322)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The signature `async function mainFunction(param: boolean) : Promise<Foo | Bar>` achieves it and is simpler, with the rest of the code unchanged

Comment: @BennyHalperin When I tried to access propB from the function's output, Typescript complained that `Property 'propB' does not exist on type 'Foo | Bar'. Did you mean 'propA'?
  Property 'propB' does not exist on type 'Bar'.ts(2551)` Does this mean that I need to write a typeguard for the output?

Comment: You need to do e.g. `(await mainFunction(true) as Foo).propB` or `(await mainFunction(false) as Bar).propC`

Comment: @BennyHalperin Ah I see, is there any way to avoid using type assertions? i.e., making TypeScript narrow the type by itself automatically?

Comment: Until [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) is implemented you'll either need to use type assertions or the like (as in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1Gqym)) or you'll have to significantly refactor the code to try to use generic indexing as in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKXlyw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, Ah, I see, well actually, using type assertions should be acceptable enough in my case, but using generic indexing is quite interesting. Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (as of TypeScript 5.4), it is impossible to implement [generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that return [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in a way the compiler can accurately verify as type safe.  There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for something better, and it looks like this issue is part of the TypeScript 5.5 roadmap at [microsoft/TypeScript#57475](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57475), and there's a pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#56941](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56941) to address it.  If that pull request or a similar one gets merged, then your code might suddenly start working as you wrote it without errors.

Until and unless that happens, if you want to keep your function the same at runtime, you'll need to use something like [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to prevent the compiler errors, opting for a lack of checking with a possible false negative instead of too-strict checking with a false positive:

```
    async function mainFunction<T extends boolean>(param: T): Promise<ConditionalFooBar<T>> {
      if (param === true) {
        return {
          propA: "a string",
          propB: "a string"
        } as ConditionalFooBar<T>
      }
      return {
        propA: "a string",
        propC: "a string"
      } as ConditionalFooBar<T>
    }
  }
```

If you need compiler-verified type safety now, you'd need to refactor away from using conditional types and toward using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) where your operation is written in terms of a property lookup instead of an `if`/`else` block.  For example:

```
    interface X {
      true: Foo;
      false: Bar;
    }

    async function mainFunction<T extends boolean>(param: T) {
      const x: X = {
        get true() {
          return {
            propA: "a string",
            propB: "a string"
          }
        },
        get false() {
          return {
            propA: "a string",
            propC: "a string"
          }
        }
      }
      return x[`${param}`]
    }
```

Here you can see that the `X` interface is just a mapping from the *string* `"true"` to `Foo` and from the *string* `"false"` to `Bar`.  And inside the function we have a value `x` of type `X`, where [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) mean we don't have to compute both the `true` and `false` branches ahead of time.  And we index into `X` with a [template literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) where `true` or `false` is serialized into `"true"` or `"false"`.

If you inspect the call signature for `mainFunction()`, it is:

```
// function mainFunction<T extends boolean>(param: T): Promise<X[`${T}`]>
```

which returns an indexed access where the key is a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) corresponding to a serialized `boolean`.  You can see that it works how you want:

```
    const a = mainFunction(true);
    //    ^? Promise<Foo>
    const b = mainFunction(false);
    //    ^? Promise<Bar>
```

And so the compiler automatically infers the type you expect when you call it.  But this version is certainly weirder than the original implementation. It might not be worth the trouble of looking up a serialized boolean key in an object implemented as a pair of getters, just for type safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAYgPbVIC8ehRSMATtTAIIBcSUxNgEtgAc2ZF2nAEJ8BwscwC++ZmQpJpINgyQB5MEOIAeGtQA0SAORSY0qwD4kAMjysOMAMJzBI0UhVmUEhYBGQuKCgINmIhamAoJhYScmRPeIATIzjQDDMtNmMAFSQIAA9iCGAMxIAjWgwIEGAnRhLyyurEwQBXZAB+JDMkPgLVZJAoUmB4JAAzHpnY+KQwEBFKRfhl4GLSiqqapHrqRuaHAAo4NnA+IoBKPgAFDkMo43Tq7PjMfO1ihxOAjJIgAelBSAAytRIPMtjskCAAO7rYiJAAWIBgFGAEAySHR0QgEhYQjmSCu2nADHojF6EHuSRBRDYEGIPTYwCZzMkHl4SAARCB+L4xALzCTmbZZILhfI-ALJSwlIjEp8sjtfrQCgClSpmaz2ZzuSDbPyhSKFKJxUreZxvLLLQq9aqkOrvrk-oUig4SfqAuMkMFoHBEEgAOJVaJCeAASWq5T8JpElTYczCSAAGiaiPS+GYANxK9MYKKjbRF5KBCZTGZwpY5VbrYCbBvxPYdQ51BpNFqUm5gO6MgiB5LweICJBlPjZxjAnmiNkkNh9C7D20sQ0crnznksM18C3ysUSvfJaWHuWi60boj+5lKU8LpclqJrnMgrfG3dng+O4-Wk+Z7uPal5OmKt4Bnu97KkqX5cmUADaAAGAAkuDXOASjIQAun6JLgvW2yNmsGzwjkHYHF0xw9uc-a3EgDzPK8QjvJmKHoUU2E4b6JLjgkxCIropEtuR8QXPS9yViwhEsAAev0fEToJtTCc2rbEeJr4MtJYIQvJil3qoShAA)